# Method to Insert Commas into Large Numbers

Tags: java, number-formatting

Is there a method that already exists and if not can a method be written that can format large numbers and insert commas into them?

```
100     = 100
1000    = 1,000  
10000   = 10,000
100000  = 100,000
1000000 = 1,000,000


public String insertCommas(Integer largeNumber) {

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `NumberFormat` you can do this easily:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);

System.out.println(format.format(100));
System.out.println(format.format(1000));
System.out.println(format.format(1000000));
```

will ouput:

```
100
1,000
1,000,000
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`NumberFormat#getNumberInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance%28java.util.Locale%29) with [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US):

> A Locale object represents a specific geographical, political, or
>   cultural region. An operation that requires a Locale to perform its
>   task is called locale-sensitive and uses the Locale to tailor
>   information for the user. For example, displaying a number is a
>   locale-sensitive operation— the number should be formatted according
>   to the customs and conventions of the user's native country, region,
>   or culture.

---

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(10000000));
```

This will print:

```
10,000,000
```

Side note: In Java 7, you can write an `int` with underscores: 1_000_000.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) (a derivation of the abstract `NumberFormat`)? You can [customise](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) the format to your needs.

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.###");
String output = myFormatter.format(value);
```

Note also that you can determine formatting based upon the *locale*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `java.text.NumberFormat`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to be very clear with what i'm doing, it could be done in much less lines.

The algorithm is simple, i reverse the input string, then i split the number using a regex, in each match we add a comma.

If the number size module 3 is zero (for example 123456) we have to remove the last comma.

Now we restore original string order by reversing it again, and voilá.

```
public String insertCommas(Integer largeNumber) {

    String result;
    String reversedNum = new StringBuilder(""+largeNumber).reverse().toString();
    String reversedResult = "";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(reversedNum);

    int lastIndex = reversedNum.length();
    while(matcher.find()){
        reversedResult += matcher.group()+",";
        lastIndex = matcher.end();
    }

    String remaining = reversedNum.substring(lastIndex);
    reversedResult += remaining; 
    result =  new StringBuilder(reversedResult).reverse().toString();
    if(remaining.isEmpty()){
        result =  new     StringBuilder(reversedResult).reverse().toString().substring(1);
    }else{
        result =  new StringBuilder(reversedResult).reverse().toString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Lol i though that he wanted to do some kind of homework. By the way, the right way to do is using NumberFormat